# Regex: How to accept at-sign (@)?

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I try to use this regex:

```
^[a-z0-9_-@]{3,15}$
```

... but it throws an exception due to the `@` sign. How can I make it accept the `@` sign?

Comment: What exception? You sure it isn't because `_` comes *after* `@`?

Comment: Have you tried this: `@"^[a-z0-9_-@]{3,15}$"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape `-`, Or move it to the beginning of the character class (`[]`):

```
@"^[a-z0-9_\-@]{3,15}$"

@"^[-a-z0-9_@]{3,15}$"
```

Without escaping `[.. _-@]` try to match characters between `_` and `@`. But there's no charcter between them: Because ASCII code of `_` and `@` is `95`, `64`. The error message address this. (Even though it match characters between `@` and `_`, it may not be what you want.)

[C# example](http://ideone.com/i24U3R)

**Reference: Error message (mono)**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: parsing "^[a-z0-9_-@]{3,15}$" - [95-64] range in reverse order.
Parameter name: ^[a-z0-9_-@]{3,15}$
  at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Syntax.Parser.ParseCharacterClass (RegexOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Now I get it. Putting '-' to the end of the line will match that character, while putting my '@' after the hyphen will make it beleive it's a range. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MojoDK, Yeah, you can put `-` to the end, but I prefer putting `-` at the beginning because that could reduce the possibility of mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `-` hyphen to the end of the regex like so:

```
^[a-z0-9_@-]{3,15}$
```